# How to get all the vertices, edges and triangles information of my scene, using the Three.js

Tags: three.js

How to get all the vertices of my scene using the Three.js

There is any way that I can get the total vertex that I have in my scene like MAYA or 3DS MAX ??.

I have some 3d models loaded with obj loader and I want to know how to get the total vertices or edges or triangles that I have inside my scene.

Like `scene.get(vertices);` or `scene.get(edges);`

Comment: There are no edge structs in three.js AFAIK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`renderer.info` is a three.js object that tallies the number of draw calls and rendered primitives. It also shows the number of geometries, textures, and shader programs in use.

```
console.log( renderer.info );
```

three.js r.84

Answer (score 2):

You can get all children of the scene with:

```
scene.children
```

And then you loop through it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i++) {

    scene.children[i].geometry.vertices
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[rstats](http://spite.github.io/rstats/) does this for you.
The source can be viewed [here](https://github.com/spite/rstats/blob/master/src/rStats.js).

Or you could look in the `scene.children` array, looking for instanced of `THREE.Mesh` which has a `geometry.vertices` array.
As an example, entering `scene.children[0].geometry.vertices` in the console on [this](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/single_color.html) page will give you an array of the vertices of the cube.

**EDIT...**
Or better still, as WestLangley points out, check the `renderer.info` object

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a straightforward answer to this question.

Edges are not present in three.js geometries, and there are a few different ways of presenting them.

Vertices can belong to triangle soups or indexed meshes, meaning different numbers for the same number of triangles.

Triangles on the other hand, are quite different if they are made to exist with `Geometry` vs `BufferGeometry`. `Geometry` has a `Face3` class which is quite complex, `BufferGeometry` has a typed array where three numbers can represent a triangle.

If you want to debug the app and see if you're accidentally creating more geometries than needed (clones by mistake or something) use `renderer.info` as per WestLangley's suggestion.

If you want to adopt someone elses semantics use something like the rstats tool in the other answer.

If you need something specific to your needs than you can ask questions like "Is it the size that matters, because then i should also perhaps count uvs as vertices", "Is it too big to hold in memory as `Geometry`", "Am i interested only in the vertex transformation performance" etc.